# newcommand wrapping lstinline does not work inside table

Tags: tables, listings

I like to have consistent documents and I like to make some decisions on formatting after I finished writing the document.  I use my own placeholder LaTeX commands to wrap some words or expressions.
For example, I'd like to use a command called `\Shortcut` to wrap `\lstinline` with a suitable style parameter. (whether I'll use `\lstinline` in the end does not matter, I may change that to `\textcolor` or whatever).
Until now my approach simply worked. But it does not work in a `tabular` environment. How can I make it work? Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstdefinestyle{inlcode}{
    language=C,
    identifierstyle=\color{blue!75!black}
}
\newcommand\Shortcut{\lstinline[style=inlcode]}

\begin{document}
  \Shortcut{test}            % <--- works

  \begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
    1 & 2 \\
    \Shortcut{one} & two   % <--- doesn't work
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the definition of your custom command to allow for the use of an argument.

The general syntax of `\newcommand` is the following:
`\newcommand{<name>}[<number of arguments>]{<code>}`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstdefinestyle{inlcode}{
    language=C,
    identifierstyle=\color{blue!75!black}
}
\newcommand{\Shortcut}[1]{\lstinline[style=inlcode]{#1}}

\begin{document}
  \Shortcut{test}

  \begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
    1 & 2 \\
    \Shortcut{one} & two
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation of why the version without an explicit argument doesn't work in tabulars?

Comment: Lstinline  is a verbatim like command. By using an argument you freeze the catcodes and actually break it.